# the row space of a 20x50 matrix A has dimension 13.what is the dimension of the space if solutions of Ax=o

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $20 \times 50$ matrix with row and column rank $r$.

I need to know the dimension of the space of solution of the system of linear equation given by $AX=0$ by the approach of linear transformation.

I see this is a map from $R^n→R^m$ given by $X↦Ax$, and hence I need to find the dimension kernel of this map.

am I right upto here?

Now how do I apply here $dim(Ker(T))+dim(Im(T))=dim(V)$ ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the rank-nullity theorem, where $$rank(A)+nullity(A)=n$$ $n$ here is the number of columns of $A$.

If the dimension of the row space of a $20\times50$ matrix $A$ is $13$, this implies $rank(A)=13$ and hence $nullity(A)=50-13=37$.

Thus the dimension of the nullspace is $37$.